# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: not working on modal view controller

Tags: ipad, ios5, delegates, modalviewcontroller, performselector

I have a modal view controller that appears, checks a service on the Internet and then dismisses itself when done. The nib contains an activity indicator and a label to inform the user what is going on.

When the update is complete, the label changes to "Update Complete" and then dismisses the view controller. However, I want it to delay the dismiss for a couple of seconds to give the user a chance to see the text before it disappears. So I've done this:

```
#pragma mark - AssetLoaderServiceDelegate

- (void)assetLoaderServiceDidFinishLoading:(AssetLoaderService *)service
{
    [self.spinner stopAnimating];
    self.infoLabel.text = @"Update complete";
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissUpdater) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
}

- (void)dismissUpdater
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But for some reason, the selector is never being called. I've tried running it in mode `NSRunLoopCommonModes` too, but that doesn't work either.

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't see what...

EDIT: The delegate callback is actually happening within an `NSOperationQueue`, which might mean it's not on the same thread when it sends the message back to the view controller? So I tried

```
[self performSelector:@selector(downloadQueueComplete) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0 inModes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSRunLoopCommonModes]];
```

followed by

```
- (void)downloadQueueComplete
{
    [delegate assetLoaderServiceDidFinishLoading:self];
}
```

But the performSelector doesn't seem to be working here either.

Comment: whether dismissUpdater is not getting called, or dismissModalViewControllerAnimated method is not working?

Comment: You mean: 1. `assetLoaderServiceDidFinishLoading` is called; 2. you modal view stays always there?

Comment: @rishi - I mean dismissUpdater is not getting called.

Comment: @sergio - yes, if I move the `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` method back into `assetLoaderServiceDidFinishLoading:`, it dismisses fine. It's the `performSelector` that's not firing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following up your suggestion about the thread issue, would you try with:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadQueueComplete) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]];
```

Comment: Yes, got the same answer at the same time, thanks! I don't appear to need the `NSRunLoopCommonModes` bit, but other than that, problem solved. Cheers :)

Comment: that's true synchronicity... and thank for accepting my answer when in fact you were there on your own...

Comment: it's only fair - I asked you guys for help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Sorted! In the AssetLoaderService, I had to perform selector on main thread:

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(downloadQueueComplete) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

After that, all the following calls were on the correct thread. :)